# Extracting ADUser from a list of AD groups in different domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have this code that extracts ADuser information from a list of AD groups, However there are some AD groups which are located on a different domain. The problem is that the code only extracts the ADuser information of the First **Domain1** mentioned on the domain list, it does not go to the other domain and extract the information of the AD group that is in a different domain.

```
$outFile=".\Output.csv"
$report=@()
$ADGroups = Get-Content ".\ADGroups.txt"

$Domains = @("Domain1.com","Domain2.com","Domain3.com","Domain4.com","Domain5.com")

foreach ($ADGroup in $ADGroups)
{

   try{

Foreach ($Domain in $Domains)


           {
$ADGroupMem = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroup  -server $Domain

ForEach ($Member in $ADGroupMem){

    $ADUser = $Member | Get-ADUser -Properties SamAccountName,Department,Title,Manager,l,Mobile
    [PSCustomObject]@{
            UserID = $ADUser.SamAccountName
            Group = $ADGroup
            City = $ADUser.l

                      } 

     $localAdminsReport = new-object PSObject
     $localAdminsReport | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserID" -Value $ADUser.SamAccountName
     $localAdminsReport | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Group" -Value  $ADGroup
     $localAdminsReport | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "City" -Value  $ADUser.l


    #Write output into .csv file
    #write-host  $report  -ForegroundColor cyan 
     write-host   $Domain                
    $report +=$localAdminsReport
    $report|Export-Csv -Path $outFile -NoTypeInformation 

                                } 
            }

         }
      Catch{}
}
```

When the report is extracted it has only extracted the information from the first Domain1 AD groups and leaves out other AD groups that are located in Domain2, Domain3.....

Comment: Try this: `$report|Export-Csv -Path $outFile -NoTypeInformation -Append` Although there are so many things wrong with your script it still should work. But try the `-Append` switch.

Comment: Why are you creating 2 objects with the same data? Your `export-csv` is writing to disk inside a 3rd nested loop. That is a lot of I/O operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Thank you Moerwald

```
    $outFile = ".\Output.csv"
    $report = @()
    $ADGroups = Get-Content ".\ADGroupslist.txt"



    foreach ($ADGroup in $ADGroups) {


    $Domains = @("Domain1","Domain2","Domain3","Domain4","Domain5")

    foreach ($Domain in $Domains)
    {


        try
        {
            $ADGroupMem = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroup -server $Domain
            ForEach ($Member in $ADGroupMem) {

                    $ADUser = $Member | Get-ADUser -Properties SamAccountName, l
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        UserID = $ADUser.SamAccountName
                        Group = $ADGroup
                        City = $ADUser.l

                                      } 
                    $localAdminsReport = new-object PSObject
                    $localAdminsReport | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserID" -Value $ADUser.SamAccountName
                    $localAdminsReport | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Group" -Value  $ADGroup
                    $localAdminsReport | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "City" -Value  $ADUser.l

                    $report += $localAdminsReport
                    $report | Export-Csv -Path $outFile -NoTypeInformation -Append
                    write-host   "$ADGroup : $Domain"   -ForegroundColor cyan   

                    }
        }
        catch
        {
             Write-Error "Exception occurred $_"

        }

    }


}
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
$report | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reworked your script. As mentioned in above comment you should use the `-Append` switch of the `Export-Csv` cmdlet. The other thing is that your `catch` clause is empty, so you won't recognize any errors. I would also recommend setting the `$ErrorPreference` to `Stop` otherwise cmdlets won't throw an error. Here is the reworked code:

```
    $outFile = ".\Output.csv"
    $report = @()
    $ADGroups = Get-Content ".\ADGroups.txt"

    $Domains = @("Domain1.com", "Domain2.com", "Domain3.com", "Domain4.com", "Domain5.com")
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    foreach ($ADGroup in $ADGroups) {
        try {
            Foreach ($Domain in $Domains) {
                $ADGroupMem = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroup -server $Domain
                ForEach ($Member in $ADGroupMem) {

                    $ADUser = $Member | Get-ADUser -Properties SamAccountName, Department, Title, Manager, l, Mobile
                    $localAdminsReport = new-object PSObject
                    $localAdminsReport | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserID" -Value $ADUser.SamAccountName
                    $localAdminsReport | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Group" -Value  $ADGroup
                    $localAdminsReport | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "City" -Value  $ADUser.l

                    $report += $localAdminsReport
                    $report | Export-Csv -Path $outFile -NoTypeInformation -Append
                } 
            }
        }
        Catch { 
            Write-Error "Exception occurred $_"
        }
    }
    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    $report | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_}
```

At the of the code the content `$report` is dumped for debugging purposes. Check if the `$report` has a difference to the exported CSV file.

You can also debug your code via [Visual Studio Code](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/debugging-powershell-script-in-visual-studio-code-part-1/), via [command line degguer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_debuggers?view=powershell-6), or via [the Powershell ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/how-to-debug-scripts-in-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-6).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the rework but the script is still behaving the same, but getting this error message, It get the ADusers from the AD group list but only those AD groups that are in domain1

$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue" : Exception occurred Cannot find an object with identity: 'ADGroup_X' under: 'DC=Domain2,DC=XXX,DC=com'.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException

Comment: Hi @Magenoob if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.